# How to replace number dot (.) with a comma (,) using java

Tags: java, string

I am having a `String str = "12.12 is a float number."` I want to replace the .(Dot) with  ,(comma) for decimal number calculation,

Currently i am trying this :

```
 system.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\d+\\.\\d+", "\\d+\\,\\d+"));
```

target output: `"12,12 is a float number."`
please help

Comment: `str.replace(".", ",")`

Comment: why don't you try this : system.out.println(str.replaceAll(".", ","));

Comment: @immibis it doesn't work because my string have other dots, and i want it.

Comment: @immibis - This will replace all dots and not just those used as decimal points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use capturing groups:

```
str.replaceAll("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)", "$1,$2")
```

Comment: If my string is dirty and it has a space before and after the dot, what should patterns be?

Comment: @AHmad Do you have an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: String str = "12 . 12 is a float number."
target: "12,12 is a float number."

Comment: Use `"(\\d+)\\s*\\.\\s*(\\d+)"` as the regular expression.